# How to make postgres pod more stable?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a **Postgres** pod running in a testing namespace, every time I ran this namespace, the pod got **evicted**, and **deleted** every time, which made everything fail with errors **50X**

I used:-

- First I used **pod disruption budgets** but it still gave me the same error.
- Second I used **priority class** with a priority of `1000000000`, it ran for several days, then started to fail.

```
50m         Normal    Scheduled                 pod/postgres-xxxxx-xxxxx                                Successfully assigned testing/postgres-xxxxxx-xxxxxx to the name of the node inside cluster
50m         Normal    Pulled                    pod/postgres-xxxxx-xxxxx                               Container image "postgres:14.4" already present on machine
50m         Normal    Created                   pod/postgres-xxxxx-xxxxx                               Created container postgres
50m         Normal    Started                   pod/postgres-xxxxx-xxxxx                               Started container postgres
50m         Warning   Unhealthy                 pod/postgres-xxxxx-xxxxx                               Readiness probe failed: /var/run/postgresql:5432 - no response
50m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate          replicaset/postgres-xxxxx                               Created pod: postgres-xxxxx-8pgfh
50m         Normal    Killing                   pod/postgres-yyyyy-yyyyy                                  Stopping container postgres
50m         Normal    SuccessfulDelete          replicaset/postgres-yyyyy                                 Deleted pod: postgres-yyyyy-yyyyy
50m         Normal    NoPods                    poddisruptionbudget/postgres-pdb                             No matching pods found
50m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet         deployment/postgres                                          Scaled down replica set postgres-yyyyy to 0 from 1
50m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet         deployment/postgres                                          Scaled up replica set postgres-xxxxx to 1
```

Now, I will try to run this pod as a **stateful set**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug why the pods are evicted.

```
kubectl describe node <node-name>
```

If the resources are exhausted then you will get evictions.